# Cannot generate embed token using access token in power bi

Tags: azure-active-directory, powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-api

I'm trying to be understand authorization mechanism in power bi API

I would embed a report in my web app.

I have done the steps as mentioned in [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/power-bi/developer/embedded/embedding)

Actually I would get report embedded url then use power bi JS API to embed the report.

Getting `access_token` is successful

```
var options = {
    'method': 'POST',
    'url': `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${process.env.TENANT_ID}/oauth2/token`,
    'headers': {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    },
    formData: {
        'grant_type': process.env.GRANT_TYPE,
        'client_id': process.env.CLIENT_ID,
        'client_secret': process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
        'resource': "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api",
        'Scope': "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default"
    }
};
```

Now I try to get [embedded token for report in group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/embedtoken/reports_generatetokeningroup#code-try-0)

```
var data = { accessLevel: "View", datasetId: "5b11d62a-803e-46c9-83f3-*****" };

var config = {
    method: 'post',
    url: `https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/${process.env.GROUP_ID}/reports/${process.env.Report_ID}/GenerateToken`,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${JSON.parse(response).access_token}`
    },
    data: data
};
let embedtoken
try {
    embedtoken = await axios(config)
}
catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
}

context.res = {
    // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
    body: JSON.parse(response).access_token
};
```

I get error `400 response`

But When I generate  [an embed token for dashboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/embedtoken/dashboards_generatetokeningroup) I get a valid token. But of course that's not working with [get report API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/getreport)

**My goal is to get report infos**. For information I get get that using the access token but it's not safe

Comment: Didn't try your code. But `datasetId` is for report creation. Only applies when generating EmbedToken for report creation. Your `accessLevel` is "View" rather than "Create". Maybe they conflict with each other. Try to remove `datasetId` if you only need "View".

Comment: Hi did you try my suggestion? Any updates?

Comment: Tried but not working ..

Answer (score 3):

For POST API requests, data should be passed in string format. This can be done by using for example, JSON.stringify(data).
Refer below code snippet which should resolve the error.

```
var config = {
 method: 'post',
 url: `https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/${process.env.GROUP_ID}/reports/${process.env.Report_ID}/GenerateToken`,
 headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${JSON.parse(response).access_token}`
 },
data: JSON.stringify(data) };
```